# Scroll div onload to bottom, as well as when updated with new data - angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'd like to essentially re-create the behavior of the iPhone's "Messages" app, in webapp form using Angularjs (or any other js honestly). I have a div that contains all my messages, then each message is a nicely controlled element as well. When a user loads the message directive, I'd like the div container to basically load at the bottom, then when a new message enters into the container I want the div to auto-scroll to the bottom.

So far the best thing I can think to do is:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
   var elem = document.getElementById('data');
   elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
}, 4000);
```

I'm using Angular so anything baked in would be nice, but everything I try/find seems slightly hacky and can't quite duplicate the same behavior as the "Messages" app.

EDIT:

I've also tried

```
$scope.$watch('messages',function(){
    console.log('messages changed')
    var elem = document.getElementById('messageDiv');
    elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
});
```

The frustrating thing here, is that this doesn't work on load, additionally, if I execute the function in Chrome's developer console, it scrolls automatically to the bottom!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately the solution that worked here was using $timeout, be sure to inject it as well...

```
 $timeout(function(){ $("#messageDiv").scrollTop($("#messageDiv")[0].scrollHeight);}, 10);
```

This allows for the action to occur when the directive is 'shown' to the user, as opposed to when loading the page.

Answer (score 0):

You should watch your collection of messages instead of scrolling down every 4 seconds (provided your messages collection is bound to the scope):

```
$scope.$watch( 'messages', function(after, before) {
    // You want to encapsulate your DOM logic inside a service
    // Later, modify it to display some smooth animation
    scrollToBottom();
} );
```

Comment: Check my edit out, so I tried this - and basically that function isn't being called or it's just not working? No errors at all, I can execute the function in Chrome's console too and it will scroll...confused!

Comment: Perhaps this has to do with the fact that I'm using directives, and the message window itself won't be visible until a user clicks to open it, and this for some reason doesn't fire when they load it?

Comment: Are you sure your messages is bound to the scope ? e.g. you have somewhere `$scope.messages = messages` ? because `$scope.$watch()` looks changes on scope variables

Comment: Yep, right before this I had `$scope.messages = Convos.getMessages();` - which is essentially what you're saying

Comment: Ok, I think you're modiying `messages` outside of angular mechanics. Angular automatically refresh the view when the model changes. But for that changes to me handled, a digest loop has to be triggered. For instance, when you call $timeout, angular launches a digest. But when you use setTimeout, it's outside angular so there's no digest and the view is not refreshed. You can look up 'angular digest cycle' to learn more about this process.